# Bootstrap - form-Inline element wrong space btn-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about Bootstrap components.

I have tried to do some number input, that's ok if I do not put into a form-inline or a navbar.

Here is the fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Lrhcezb/

[image]

First input are Ok... Now, if I focused in the other input, this doesn't get the right size.

[image]

Can I fix it with bootstrap or I need to do my own div control?

Thanks!

--

Guys this occour with the 3.5.5 bootstrap version.

I have updated in Fiddle, and now I can show you my problem...

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Lrhcezb/4/

Comment: Works in Chrome. Which browser you are using?

Comment: It works(Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m)

Comment: Yes, I have tested in the chrome. In the IE this works. (amazingly :P)

Comment: My chrome version: Versão 45.0.2454.101 m

Comment: I have update chrome, but it doesn't work yet!

Answer (score 0):

Guys this occour with the 3.5.5 bootstrap version.

I have updated in Fiddle, and now I can show you my problem...

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Lrhcezb/4/